# How do I add those code wrappers that wrap a block by myself?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, word-wrap

They are automatically added on every block, however, if I want to wrap more than a block, it does not allow my that functionality. 
[image]

How can i put them myself in my code? If I, for example want to have them here and here: [image: Only one of these to wrap it all.]

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

For C++, use `#pragma region`

```
#pragma region "Some self-explanatory name"

. . .

#pragma endregion
```

For C#, `#region` works

Also, see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/td6a5x4s(v=vs.100).aspx

Alternatively, if you don't want to write `region` directives, select the code you want to hide and press <kbd>Ctrl + M</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl + H</kbd>.

Comment: 1) It is not only for C++ 2) You don't actually need the name

Comment: @Rakete1111 The question was tagged C++. 1) `#pragma region` doesn't work in `C#` 2) I never said it's mandatory.

Comment: @Shreevardhan Well, [but it works for every language](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b6xkz944.aspx) - I figure. But you also never said it is optional

Answer (score 0):

Select those lines, then right click and Select "Outlining -> Hide Selection"

Another way is to add a `#region` but this alters the source